# how to find a username with the github api

Tags: api, rest, graphql, github-api, dependabot

I've made an application that creates pull requests to update the dependencies in all of my org's repos when the repo "Alpha" gets a new tag.  The process is triggered by our CI flow on Alpha. Other engineers here would like to upgrade this application so that whoever made the tag is also automatically added as a requested reviewer to all of the associated pull requests.  I do not see any way to do this with the [github REST api](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/endpoints-available-for-github-apps).  So far I have:

```
GET tag by name -> tag object sha
GET tag (with obj sha) -> tagger name & tagger email
*************GAP**************
POST requested reviewer (with username) -> completed!
```

I can't see any good way to get a username from the REST api with the name and/or email. I could query commits from Alpha and filter them, BUT "person who tagged" != "person who made last commit AND I know that at least one of our more prolific taggers is sometimes logged in from different emails (web vs cli vs home machine, etc), so the app might miss them from time to time.

I think it may be possible to get what I want via the GraphQL api, but I'd really like to exhaust REST possibilities before I go down that road.  Please shoot any ideas my way!

Comment: If you're using events triggered by Github webhooks, the event itself has the "sender.login" property that contains the username. Can you use that, or do you HAVE to get it from the API?

Comment: Sadly the process is triggered via our CI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After gathering more information, it looks like it's possible, and even slightly more elegant than I anticipated. If I have the name of the tag (the 'ref'), I can get a specific commit with that rather than the SHA.  the response for this commit includes author information that gives the login.  I can then use this along with the pull number to request a reviewer.